# Merge two dataset in Python with hierarchical conditions

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, merge, left-join

I am very new to Python and I was trying to merge two tables using pandas with certain conditions

The first table may look like below

**Table 1**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Mark |
| 4 | Andy |

The second table may look like below

**Table 2**

| ID | status_code |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **1** |
| **1** | **2** |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

The output table that I am trying to make will be the one in below

** Output Table **

| ID | Name | status_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Jane** | **1** |
| 2 | John | 1 |
| 3 | Mark | 2 |
| **4** | **Andy** | **3** |

So people like Jane who has both 1 and 2 for 'status_code' in second table, I want to use 1 instead of 2 for that column.
And for people like Andy who does not have any code in second table, I want to put 3 instead of NA.

I would really appreciate help for this
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map, since you are joining on one column and returning one column.

```
df1['status_code'] = df1['ID'].map(df2.drop_duplicates('ID').set_index(['ID']).squeeze()).fillna(3)
```

Ouptut:

```
   ID  Name  status_code
0   1  Jane          1.0
1   2  John          1.0
2   3  Mark          2.0
3   4  Andy          3.0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I just wanted to ask whether drop_duplicate will only delete the status_code "2" and not "1" for 'Jane' since Jane has both 1 and 2 for df2.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

Firstly merge both df's by `merge()` method,then we sort values of 'status_code' column by `sort_values()` method and then remove duplicates by `drop_duplicates()` method:

```
df=df1.merge(df2,on='ID',how='left').sort_values('status_code').drop_duplicates(subset='Name')
```

Finally use boolean masking:

```
df.loc[df['Name']=='Andy','status_code']=3
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
    ID  Name    status_code
0   1   Jane    1.0
2   2   John    1.0
3   3   Mark    2.0
4   4   Andy    3.0
```

**Note:** here df1 is your Table1 and df2 is your Table2

Comment: If I merge two df's, I would get Jane with statuse_code 1 and another row with status_code 2, How do I make sure that drop_duplicates will only eliminate the row with 2 and not 1

Comment: drop_duplicate method by default remove the duplicate values keeping the first occurence ....you can use sort_values method